How to find percent from drop down options in google sheets?
I use a rubric for data collection. I am trying to compile it onto a spreadsheet for user-friendly accessibility. I have put the content criteria in separate column drop down menus. I need to calculate the percent for each column, and each drop down item individually.

I have tried =PERCENTIF(B4:B11,"1") and the percent is wrong.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

What is a percentage? Are you assigning a value based on the number of the response 5=90%, 4=80%, 3=70% etc. Or looking for a percentage for how many times the same block of text shows up in each column?

I think the basic syntax you are looking for is:
=PERCENTIF(range, "1*")

If you want a single formula to calculate all your percentages, for all the columns, you could try the following:
=LET(range,A2:C, answers,5, seq,SEQUENCE(answers),
   headers,{"Answer #", INDEX("Col. "&
     REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(range),4),"[A-Z]*"))}, 
   {headers; seq, BYCOL(FILTER(A1:C, A1:A<>""), LAMBDA(c, 
     MAP(seq, LAMBDA(r, PERCENTIF(c, r & "*")))))})

ADDRESS  BYCOL  COLUMN  FILTER  INDEX  LAMBDA  LET  REGEXEXTRACT  SEQUENCE

answers stores the number of possible answers, currently set to 5.
seq returns a number SEQUENCE based on the number of answers.
headers contains the column headers, the first for the answer number, and the rest, "Col." is joined to each column letter from range.
Finally headers and seq are returned along with an array of percentages which is created  by:

Using BYCOL to pass range, after removing blank rows using FILTER, into a LAMBDA function, column by column, which stores the current column in c
The LAMBDA's formula is a MAP function that passes seq into another LAMBDA, row by row, which stores the current row in r (each r is a different answer number).
That LAMBDA's formula uses PERCENTIF with the range set to the current column c and the search string set to the current answer number r joined to a wildcard operator r&"*".
Once every r has been processed for the current c the process is repeated for the next c until all c have been processed.



